# Is there a way to change the default drag and drop action in macOS to file/folder move, instead of copy?

Tags: macos, finder, default-settings

The drag and drop default in macOS Mojave (10.14.3) appears to be to copy and not move. Is there a way to change the default drag and drop action to file/folder move, instead of copy?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to override the default behaviour.

Default is to Move if it is to the same volume, Copy if to a different volume.

You can override any specific drag by holding  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  to Move to another volume, or holding  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  to Copy to the same volume.
You can also use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  to copy, then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  to Move instead of Copy [in effect, a Cut/Paste operation].

Answer (score -1):

System preferences > Accessibility > Pointer Control
In the Mouse & Trackpad tab you can adjust double click speed and spring-loading delay. If you uncheck the Spring-loading delay box, it will prevent the folder from opening when you drag and hover a file over a folder..

This was mainly what I was looking to do when I was searching for answers and stumbled upon this site. Maybe it'll be helpful to someone else in the future. Best regards, all.

Answer (score -2):

Go into: System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Preferences ->  All Controls.  You can change the default setting in there.

Comment: 1)That's a long way round to the Keyboard prefs, which are accessible directly from the main panel & 2) what there would you need to change to enable what the OP is asking?

Comment: Agree with @Tetsujin that that's the long way to the Keyboard Preferences, but I tried it that way just to see if there's anything different when entered from that "direction".  Couldn't see it.  I think planetehack is missing a step in there, after Keyboard Prefs, you need to click on "Shortcuts", and then there is an "All Controls" checkbox.  But, that only lets you change how the Tab key operates.  I don't think this answers the original question...